# AsyncLoading VS AsyncValue.loading

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I am trying to create Auth and Todo app.
The problem is that I don't know which is the correct usage and
don't know the difference between the two.

I want to use it before adding an item to the Todo List.

Is there a clear distinction between them, or do they have the same meaning?

I saw common.dart file but it written like this.

````dart
 /// Creates an [AsyncValue] in loading state.
  ///
  /// Prefer always using this constructor with the `const` keyword.
  // coverage:ignore-start
 const factory AsyncValue.loading() = AsyncLoading<T>;```
````

Comment: This seems to be a Riverpod specific class. You may want to read one of their tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same.
AsyncData, AsyncError and AsyncLoading are just syntax sugar for different states of AsyncValue

here is the implementation from the library, it is indeed the same.

```
  const factory AsyncValue.data(T value) = AsyncData<T>;

  const factory AsyncValue.loading() = AsyncLoading<T>;
```